# Windows 7 - 64bit - Half the memory is not usable on some boots

Tags: windows-7, memory, 64-bit

I have found some similar questions but they have not helped me thus far.

The **problem** I have is that I have 8gb ram (2x4gb modules) and about two thirds of the time only the 4gb are usalbe, and on one third I have 8gb usable.

My **question** is where is the problem originating from because I was considering buying 2x8gb memory, but not knowing what the issue is I might have the same/similar problem again.

So I am looking at either fixing the issue or ruling out some cases so I can decide to spend the money to get new memory.

**PC specs**

- AMD Core 8 (FX-8150) 3.6GHz Processor 8MB
- Corsair 8GB (2X4GB) DDR3 1600Mhz Vengeance Blue "LOW PROFILE" CL9 1.5V
- Asus M5A99X EVO 990X Socket AM3+ 8 Channel Audio ATX Motherboard

**Things I tried but have not made a consistent difference**

- Moved the two modules from one band to the other one (from the two blue slots to the two black slots in the motherboard)
- Ticked / unticked the msconfig use maximum memory setting

**Screenshots**

It seems that because this is a new account I can only have one screenshot, so I include what speccy shows when only half the memory is usable.

**4gb usable out of 8gb installed**

The 'system' in control panel reports:

- 8.00 gb (3.95 GB usable)
- 64-bit Operating System

[image: Speccy ram screenshot]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to be a hardware issue.

I would recommend re-seating both RAM modules and CPU, but after removing and before putting them back together clean the sockets with compressed air. Dust particles can conduct current.

Since you can see both memory modules some of the time I'd pay more attention to CPU.

If that doesn't help, it might be that either one of RAM modules or MB are faulty.

Comment: Re-seating and air cleaning did not make a difference.

Comment: sigh, cannot edit yet, full update: Re-seating and air cleaning did not make a difference. In the end I decided to risk it and bought 2x8gb memory to replace the 2x4 i had. So far they have had no problems. So it probably was a problem with one of the ram modules